# Showing computed properties in components

Tags: vue.js

I just came upon [Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) section (One-way data flow) and I can't figure out how to show computed properties from them.

```html
<div id="demo">
  <input v-model="parentMsg"/>
  <child v-bind:my-message="parentMsg"></child>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
var Child = {
  props: ['myMessage'],
  template: '<span>{{ lowerCaseMsg }}</span>',
  computed: {
    lowerCaseMsg: function() {
        return this.myMessage.trim().toLowerCase();
    }
  }
});

var data = {
    parentMsg: 'Message'
}

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: data,
    components: {
        child: Child
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code:

```js
var Child = {
  props: ['myMessage'],
  template: '<span>{{ lowerCaseMsg }}</span>',
  computed: {
    lowerCaseMsg: function() {
        return this.myMessage.trim().toLowerCase();
    }
  }
});  // Extraneous )
```

Comment: It works for me: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/decademoon/df4Lnuw6/150/).

Comment: Works for me now too, I accidentally wrote `myMessage()` instead of `myMessage` - thanks!